# Error objects, native and custom, how to tell the difference?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, error-handling

In my node app I want to work with custom errors as well as native errors. I always seem to struggle with error handling because errors seem to be a special type of object, not a normal JavaScript object.

I'm trying to use [errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/errors) for custom errors.

What I want to end up with is a JSON string that I can return to the client, for both types of error (custom and native).

I can create a custom error like:

```
errors.create({
  name: `UnableToDelete`,
  defaultMessage: `Unable to perform delete.`
});
let e1 = new errors.UnableToDelete({
  explanation: `Group has members. You can't delete a group that has members.`
});
```

I can create a native error like:

```
let e2 = new Error(`Unable to perform delete.`);
```

I might also get a native error from somewhere else, like from node, or another third party module, for example if something goes wrong while connecting to a database.

- For the custom error I can use `JSON.stringify(e1);` which works.
- For the native error I can use `errors.errorToJSON(e2);` which works.

The problem I have is being able to tell the difference between these errors, so I can call the right method on it.

*I don't want to have to wrap every error, everywhere in my code, in the correct method*. I want to have my Express error handler do that:

```
function error(err, req, res, next) {
    // use either JSON.stringify() or errors.errorToJSON() on
    // the err object. 
}
```

How can I tell the difference between a custom and native error, in order to know which method to use..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodejs module `errors` exports a function called `isError(err)` that will return `true` if you send a custom error created by the module.

```
var customError = new errors.HttpError();
var nativeError = new Error();
errors.isError(customError); // Will return true
errors.isError(nativeError); // Will return false
```

Comment: That seems to work. Unless I'm being stupid, the word "isError" doesn't appear on either this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/errors or this page: https://github.com/bodenr/errors. How did you find this seemingly hidden method..??

Comment: Found it in the source: https://github.com/bodenr/errors/blob/master/lib/errors.js#L112. It just checks for the `explanation` and `code` properties. Strange it's not in the docs.

Comment: I found that method looking at the tests in: https://github.com/bodenr/errors/blob/master/test/test.js#L257 Maybe they forgot to add this method to the docs...